# Random "Uncaught runtime errors" messages after upgrading to latest CRA and Node 18

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Our DevOps team informed us that they will be upgrading all servers to Node 18. But our app was working properly only with Node 16. So I upgraded CRA to latest version and at first it seems fine. But then random "Uncaught runtime errors" overlay messages begin popping up in development mode. They are completely random, when I click a link sometimes it shows up, the next time it doesn't show up. I can't find the source of the problem according to error messages. Message are always like this:

```
Uncaught runtime errors:
×
ERROR
Cancel
    at handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:614149:58)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:614172:7
```

When I look at console, it is like this:

```
Uncaught (in promise) 
Cancel {message: undefined}
message: undefined
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

When I look at the specified rows at bundle.js, they are like this:

bundle.js:614149:58

```
var handleError = function handleError(error, fallbackMessage) {
     **var errorObject = error instanceof Error ? error : new Error(error || fallbackMessage);**
      var shouldDisplay = typeof options.catchRuntimeError === "function" ? options.catchRuntimeError(errorObject) : true;
      if (shouldDisplay) {
        overlayService.send({
          type: "RUNTIME_ERROR",
          messages: [{
            message: errorObject.message,
            stack: (0,_overlay_runtime_error_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.parseErrorToStacks)(errorObject)
          }]
        });
```

bundle.js:614172:7

```
(0,_overlay_runtime_error_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.listenToUnhandledRejection)(function (promiseRejectionEvent) {
   **var reason = promiseRejectionEvent.reason;**
      handleError(reason, "Unknown promise rejection reason");
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the source of the problem. Latest version of webpack-dev-server has a new feature described as "Overlay displays unhandled promise rejection". This was causing the problem, downgrading to previous version solved it.

```
npm install webpack-dev-server@4.14.0 --save --save-exact --save-dev
```

Comment: I don't have webpack-dev-server installed as a package. Where and how should I downgrade that package?

Comment: npm install webpack-dev-server@4.14.0 --save --save-exact --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

issue with the webpack-dev-server in create react app. Check your Node.js and create-react-app versions and make sure they are compatible with each other. You can use `node -v and npx create-react-app --version` to check your versions. If they are outdated or mismatched, you can try to update them or downgrade them to a stable version.

I am experiencing the same problem. I downgraded CRA and the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add following in your webpack config

```js
{
  devServer: {
    client: {
      overlay: false, // <- add this
    }
  }
}
```

Ref - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#overlay